# How to add items to TableView without Restarting the Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

In my app I have a table view controller with two buttons. One adds an item, and the other edits the table view. When I add an item, the console says that it has added an item, but it's not until i restart the simulator to see that items are being added to the table view. When I add an item I make sure to reload the tableview like so:

```
- (IBAction)addNewItem:(id)sender

{
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
Item *itemData = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[itemData setValue:userText.text forKey:@"name"];

NSError *error;

if (![context save:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"Couldnt find the save %@", error.localizedDescription);
}

else
{
    NSLog(@"It saved properly");
}

[self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

I just don't understand what the problem could be...

All help is appreciated,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Without seeing your `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection` methods it will be hard to know the reason for the problem.

Comment: And do you really need to restart the simulator or just restart the app?

Comment: well the app, sorry i should have worded the question better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tableView keep to show the old fetch result after the new item has been added. You need to  fetch the data again after item has been added and then call the [self.tableView reloadData] method.